# Date with time stamp is not storing

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

This is the Date value that client is sending

```
createdOn : "2017-09-14T13:23:44"
```

In Controller client value is mapping to the Dto, AttachmentsDto

```
public class AttachmentsDto implements Serializable {

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timezone="Asia/Muscat")
    private Date createdOn;
}
```

Below is the Attachment Entity

```
public class Attachments implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="CREATED_ON", insertable= true, updatable=false)
    private Date createdOn;
    }
```

Service have written code to save the entire dto.

mapped dto to entity and called repo save here.

```
attachmentsRepo.save(mapper.map(AttachmentsDto, Attachments.class)), AttachmentsDto.class);
```

Here its saving only date there is no timestamp.

Db `createdOn = 9/14/2017`

How can I store date and timestamp ?

Comment: Which database are you using and what type is the `createdOn` column in this database?

Comment: Using Oracle database

Comment: ...and the datatype in oracle for this column is...?

Comment: data type is Date,  this is not an issue I tried saving it in db manually with timestamp